# How to write MS Unit test for Exception when exception throws, write custom message to console

Tags: c#, unit-testing, try-catch, nullreferenceexception, assert

I wrote a method that write a list of persons to text file and in unit test I want to check if I pass NULL for list, NullReferenceException is throwing.

Method

```
public void WriteToOutput(List<Person> list)
        {
            string outputFileName = "names-list.txt";
            try
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFileName, false);

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.givenNames + " " + item.lastName);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.givenNames + " " + item.lastName);//writting names to console
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit...");
                sw.Close();

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List is Empty");
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
        }
```

Test Method

```
[TestMethod]
        public void WriteToOutput_NullableList_ThrowNullReferenceException()
        {
            //arrange
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter();

            //act
            Assert.ThrowsException<NullReferenceException>(()=> fw.WriteToOutput(null));

        }
```

But I don't want to throw NullReferenceException in the WriteToOutput method but only to write message to console. if I remove 'throw new NullReferenceException' from method 'WriteToOutput' my test is failling.

Any Opinion for how to handle this.

Comment: So you want the test to assert that "List is Empty" is written to the Console?

Comment: you need to edit this question and title because you don't actually want to test for exceptions

Answer (score 1):

First you'd remove the dependency on `Console` and change it to `Action<string>`.

```
public class FileWriter
{
    public Action<string> Log { get; set; }

    public void WriteToOutput(List<Person> list)
    {
        ...
        Log("List is Empty");
    }
}
```

Now you can plug in delegates as needed.

```
 var writer = new FileWriter();
 writer.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

And the class would write to Console.

For the tests we provide a different delegate.

```
[TestMethod]
public void WriteToOutput_NullableList_ThrowNullReferenceException()
{
    var message = "";
    Action<string> testlog = (string msg) => { message = msg; };

    var writer = new FileWriter();
    writer.Log = testlog;

    Assert.AreEqual(message, "List is Empty");
}
```

Comment: But I'd just re-throw the exception `throw ex` and test for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a TextWriter for the output

```
public class FileWriter
{
    private readonly TextWriter _console;

    public FileWriter(TextWriter console)
    {
        _console = console;
    }

    public void WriteToOutput(List<Person> list)
    {
        string outputFileName = "names-list.txt";
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFileName, false))
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.GivenNames + " " + item.LastName);
                    _console.WriteLine(item.GivenNames + " " + item.LastName); //writting names to console
                }
                _console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit...");
                sw.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            _console.WriteLine("List is Empty");
        }

    }
}
```

then in tests

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var fw = new FileWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
    //act
    fw.WriteToOutput(null);
    Assert.AreEqual("List is Empty\r\n", sb.ToString());
```

and in a program to the console

```
var peopleWriter = new FileWriter(Console.Out);
```

Then you can also test your main case

```
fw.WriteToOutput(new List<Person>()
{
   new Person() { GivenNames = "Dula", LastName = "Hula" },
   new Person() {GivenNames = "Ruby", LastName = "Nooby"}
});
Assert.AreEqual("Dula Hula\r\nRuby Nooby\r\nPress Enter to Exit...\r\n", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to throw exception if List of Person is null, then your test should be opposite of your success test (when list is with records). This way you don't depend on console message. 
OR 
you can change your method WriteToOutput to return bool and then in test you check for return value i.e.

```
    public void WriteToOutput(List<Person> list)
    {
        string outputFileName = "names-list.txt";
        try
        {
            // other stuff
            return true;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List is Empty");
            return false;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void WriteToOutput_NullableList_ThrowNullReferenceException()
    {
        //arrange
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter();

        //act
        bool returnValue = fw.WriteToOutput(null);

        //assert
        Assert.IsFalse(returnValue);
    }
```